# How do I correctly allow CORS when using an Angular app to consume a Rails backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Here is my Rails app's application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_filter :add_allow_credentials_headers

  def add_allow_credentials_headers
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = request.headers['Origin'] || '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
  end
end
```

This is my Angular app's controller using the $http service and a custom factory:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('usausa', []).controller('obtainPovertyData',
  ['$scope', '$http', 'getPovertyData', function($scope, $http, getPovertyData) {
  getPovertyData.getPoverty().success(function(data){
    console.log("hi")
    console.log(data)
  }).error(function(error){
    console.log("hi1")
    console.log(error)
  })
}]);
```

This is my getPovertyData factory:

```
'use strict';
var usausa = angular.module('usausa');
usausa.factory('getPovertyData', ['$http', function($http){
  return {
    getPoverty: function() {
      return $http.get('localhost:3000/api/v1/poverty/data')
    }
  }
}])
```

Right now my rails endpoint is just on localhost:3000. My angular app is running on localhost:5555. I'm using Chrome. For some reason when I run my angular app and visit my index.html, I see this in my console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000/api/v1/poverty/data. Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
>   chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Why is this happening? I thought I solved this issue no when I allowed the request to come from any origin?

Comment: this has nothing to do with angular

Comment: What does it have to do with?

Comment: CORS is a server configuration issue that has nothing to do with the client

Comment: It's weird to me that CORS (seemingly to protect the server from any client making sensitive AJAX requests that may alter resources) is something on the client side. With that said, it looks like my rails API is allowing requests from any origin. So, why am I still having this problem?

Comment: because there is more involved than 2 headers. Is server configured to process OPTIONS requests and all the CORS headers required for those?

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) which you can use to configure cross origin requests in your Rails app.

For example, to allow request under `/api` route, use the following config:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '/api/*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

Comment: tried this, still have a problem. Is this a problem caused my chrome or localhost?

Comment: I use both chrome and localhost without problems. Try 'resource *' first